# get blob error after using watchify to make a bundle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, watchify

**What I am trying to do?** 
I want to create a project using node modules and es6 javascript syntax. To make it as modular and independent as it is possible, I decided to switch to watchify. 
My html page is looking something like this

```
...some unrelated html code

<dib id='content'></div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='correct(checked) path to my bundle.js file'></script>

...some unrelated html code
```

my whatchify command is look like this

```
watchify src/app.js -o destination/bundle.js -t [babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]
```

while my dependenties look like this is looks like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "three": "^0.92.0",
    "three-obj-exporter": "0.0.1",
    "three-obj-loader": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.4"
  }
```

for now there is no much in my src file I just imported a test function from a test.js file and required jquery.

```
import print from './taskobject';

function test(){
    return 0;
}
```

**Now, whats I don't understand?**
Literally I do nothing, but I still keep getting the following error in console

```
GET blob:http://127.0.0.1/fbfa8eff-f538-42cf-aa2d-ae2940247aaf 0 ()
(anonymous) @ inject.preload.js:373
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap a58e717ca664391e8660:19
splitSelector.splitSelector @ common.js:103
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap a58e717ca664391e8660:19
exports.textToRegExp @ bootstrap a58e717ca664391e8660:62
(anonymous) @ bootstrap a58e717ca664391e8660:62
```

**A question?**
Do I need webpack to use watchify/browserify? Do I used all preset I needed for "compiling" es6+node code? What have I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this error is caused by a recent bug in Adblocker. https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6744

Try different browsers with and without Adblocker and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think you right. I mean I have tried the same code on mozilla firefox and I don't get this error. It's seems more chrome + adkblock issue to me. The reason is, I have tried mozilla with adk but it haven't showed the same error