# GET "Blob" error in console - Chrome Only

Tags: javascript, git, google-chrome

I linked my Namecheap to my Github pages and everything was running smoothly until recently. When I load my "Portfolio" page which has .PNG images of the different projects, none of the images load. I get this error:

GET blob:https://www.jacoblhughes.com/ef478fb8-2118-423f-b43d-26ac32213ead 0 ()

Unfortunately I do not have any idea what this means so I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated! I am getting this error in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888287/get-blob-error-after-using-watchify-to-make-a-bundle), this problem is caused by a [bug in Adblocker](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6744). Try and disable the extension, and it should disappear.

Comment: Hmm, so I disabled Adblocker and now while I do not get that error message, I do not see the pictures either. Perhaps my coding is the problem...did you see anything else?

Comment: I have a similar error. I disabled adblocker, reloaded, and I'm still getting this error.